# Problem with using Cyrillic letters in URL in shinyapps.io

Tags: cyrillic, flexdashboard, shinyapps

I want to create a multipage dashboard using a flexdashboard with shiny. I deployed my dashboard on shinyapps.io, but I can’t open pages with titles in Russian (pages named in English are ok). I think this is because of some problems with using Cyrillic symbols in URL. Is it possible to use Russian titles of pages on my dashboard?

```
---
title: "Title"
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
  orientation: columns
runtime: shiny
---
Page 1
====================================
Column 
------------------------------------
Column
------------------------------------
### Заголовок
### Заголовок

Страница 2
====================================
Column 
------------------------------------
### Заголовок
Column 
------------------------------------
### Заголовок

Страница 3
====================================
Column
------------------------------------
### Заголовок
### Заголовок
Column
------------------------------------
### Заголовок
### Заголовок

Page 4
====================================
Column
------------------------------------
### Заголовок
### Заголовок
Column
------------------------------------
### Заголовок
```

https://evgeniia-volkova.shinyapps.io/dashboard/